# Google Places API always return error

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have integrated Google Places API in my android application.
I have read the api documentation [See Here](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search).

I have activated Google Places Api for android and generated browser key
and when i call api get error in response -

```
{"error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I also try creating android key and it return -

```
{
 "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
 "html_attributions" : [],
 "results" : [],
 "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I am not getting what the problem in my code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Check API Console - [image]

Comment: can you give the url you have used?

Comment: @Sandeep Singh Check this -https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=SEARCH_STRING&key=API_KEY&radius=DIFINED_RADIUS&location=CURRENT_LAT,CURRENT_LONGI

Comment: KISS use correct API key (Browser Key)

Comment: Also try using browser key,Check my question

Comment: Try to change your API key because the url you give to me its working fine, I have test it with my api key.

Comment: Delete Previous key->Create new one->Uninstall apk from device->reinstall apk->try searching places again same error.

Comment: have you enable Place API in google console API menu ?

Comment: Using same api key I am able to display google map.

Comment: After lots of search found the solution by activating 'Google Places API Web Service' api from console.I am not sure this is correct way or not,Because it is an paid api and I am using it on android and it is an  web api.

Comment: I used Android key with both Places Android API and Places Web Service (free now) enabled and it worked.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. In my case the problem was that I tried to send request using simple HttpUrlconnection by this url:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=62.25227243964484%2C59.12338379770518&radius=500&key=my_key
```

Where my_key was a key for **Google Places API for Android**, but when I switched to **Google Places API Web Service**, this works fine. It seems that for using key for Google Places API for Android you should follow this guide https://developers.google.com/places/android/

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're using the Places API Web Service, which requires enabling "Google Places API Web Service" and providing a server key: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro#Authentication

Since you're building an Android application, you may want to try the Places API for Android, which we just released in March :) The documentation is available at https://developers.google.com/places/android/

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but i am getting same error. I have enabled Places API for Android.

Comment: Agreed. Enabling  the Google Places API Web Service is required.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by following below prerequisites:

1) Make sure you are using below URL

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=YOURSEARCHTEXT&key=YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY.
>   Don't use your android/IOS API key.

2) Make sure you have enabled following API in the console.

> Google Places API Web Service (Paid Service)

Comment: after enableing Google Places API Web Service (Free Service) .. Its working for me... Thnkx @Shoaib

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas +1 for Free service worked for me too. And I used Android key with both Places Android API and Places Web Service enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I was also suffered from this problem but enabling **"Google Places API Web Service"** worked for me.

The problem is that we are using Google Places's Web Service for getting Places and we are forget to enable **[Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/)** in Google developer console.

So please make sure that whenever you are using Google Place API and don't forget to enable **Google Maps Android API**  and **Google Places API Web Service** .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Have you enabled Google Places API Web Service.
Because Google Places API for Android not for it.
hope it will work.
if not
then use a simply url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&components=country:gr&input=YOUR_INPUT_VALUE" like POSTJSON
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While using google places api you android api key will not work , create a server key and use that server in in the places url while making request. In manifest your same android api key will lie. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this many time util I found the solution

if you will send Url from your app to get place information then you are using
**Google Places API Web Service** not  **Google Places API for Android**

So you must enable `Google Places API Web Service` on your API Dashboard and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android API is instead of Browser and Server API key. Was facing the same problem but resolved using Android API key.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Google Maps Geocoding API" after enable the "Google Maps Android API"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have '**Google Places API Web Service**' enable, and you must use a **Server Key** (not an Android key)

[image: Enable api]

[image: set credential]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by enabling Geocoding api in the developer console.